# How to keep Scala Process Alive?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I type "sbt run", and compilation is ok, the server binds to the port, and then the process quietly terminates. How can I keep the process alive though? (I'm running an akka tcp server pulled straight from the akka docs -- should remain alive.)

Pseudocode:

```
object Main extends App {
    val ac = ActorSystem();
    val s = ac.actorOf(WebSocketManager.props());
}
```

Edit: The process stays alive after adding into **build.sbt**:

```
Compile / run / fork := true
```

Not sure what this does or if correct, but it works.

Comment: Please provide some code sample

Comment: Is your server waiting for a signal to be terminated? Does it wait for e.g. input stream to end with Ctrl+D?

Comment: My best guess as to what you pulled - https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.6.19/akka-docs/src/test/scala/docs/io/EchoServer.scala - the main waits for keyboard input before telling the actorSystem to terminate. Assuming this is what you copied, try just not calling `system.terminate()` (or using some other trigger to terminate it)

Comment: Updated the post!